# Error Migración con relaciones laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Obtengo un error al crear migración uno a muchos con tabla users y generos_usuarios.

Migración users:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('apellidos');
            $table->string('dni');
            $table->string('celular1');
            $table->string('celular2')->nullable();;
            $table->string('convencional')->nullable();;
            $table->string('estado');
            $table->string('rol');
            $table->string('email1');
            $table->string('email2')->nullable();;
            $table->string('ext_foto')->nullable();
            //$table->string('genero_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreignId('genero_id')->nullable()
            ->constrained('generos_usuarios')
            ->cascadeOnUpdate()
            ->nullOnDelete();


        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Migracion generos_usuarios .

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class GenerosUsuarios extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('generos_usuarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('generos_usuarios');
    }
}
```

Foto de todas mis migraciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto de Error en consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probá hacer que la migración de "generos_usuarios" corra antes que la de "users". En la tabla "users" estás haciendo una referencia a "generos_usuarios" pero esa tabla se crea después, es probable que ese sea el problema. Simplemente cambiale la fecha al archivo para que quede primero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero se ejecuta la migración que crea los usuarios y después la de **generos_usuarios**, entonces cuando se intenta crear el foreingId **genero_id**, no es posible porque la tabla a la que hace referencia (generos_usuarios) aun no existe.

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiarle el nombre a la migración que crea los usuarios (Colocarle en el nombre con una fecha superior a la que tiene la de generos) para que se ejecute primero la migración de géneros